# Firebase notifiactions are not working execpt my own device

Tags: json, firebase

I use JSON to send notification with Firebase to my android app.

I recive in my Android device all notifications sent, but no other user whose token is under users does not receive them.

Is there something wrong with the code that send the notifications?

```
def send_push (thedate):
    users = get_users()
    for i in xrange(len(users) / 1000 + 1):
        url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        body = {
            "data": {
                "title": "{0} is available in {1}!!".format(thedate, book_name),
                "message": "New available books. Click here to open the booking site!",
                "type": "open_book",
                "click_action": "open_book",
                "book_id": book_id,
                "theDate": thedate,
                "url": "https://bookings.doc.govt.nz/Saturn/Facilities/SearchViewGW.aspx?placeId="+DOCtrekID
            },
            "registration_ids": users[i * 1000:((i + 1) * 1000 - 1)]
        }
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "key=***key***"
        }
        d = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
        print d
    print users

send_push("23/10/2018")
```